# Synchronizing a heavy/long-loading method in Angular and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

We're using TypeScript and Angular 6 in our project, and have an injectable service class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    getAllProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return this.http.get('/products')
    }
}
```

Then, buried deep on one of our Angular page, are a **three** separate components that each want access to this product list.

We would like to allow each component to use:

```
this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe(products => ...)
```

But this starts **three** separate HTTP calls, with client-side JSON parsing, etc.

The short-sighted route would be to get the `Product[]` **once** in the outer-most page, and pass that data all the way down to the component. I dislike this because our code gets crufty and each intermediate component now has one more thing it needs to carry/pass down to the children.

If this were Java, I'd just `synchronize` access on the `getAllProducts()` method and cache the result in the `ProductService`, returning the cached copy if it exists.

How can I achieve a similar (fast + clean) result using Angular/TypeScript?

Comment: In javascript your code runs on single thread. It's synchronized by default, so go ahead with your caching option.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for RxJS's share operator.

```
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){
    this.dataFromServer$ = this.httpClient.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    this.sharedData$ = this.httpClient.get<any[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').pipe(share()) 

    // Creates 3 Requests
    this.dataFromServer$.subscribe()
    this.dataFromServer$.subscribe()
    this.dataFromServer$.subscribe()


    // Creates 1 Request
    this.sharedData$.subscribe()
    this.sharedData$.subscribe()
    this.sharedData$.subscribe()
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsw7zq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Sometimes it is recommendable to use **shareReplay**. When the subscription might happen after the request succeeds.

For further reading, I can recommend the keywords "angular hot / cold observable".